# How to use python and BeautifulSoup to print timestamp/last updated time (from HTML) for each row?

Tags: python

How to use python and BeautifulSoup to print timestamp/last updated time (from HTML) for each row?

1. Can I add the print

   a) date/time - display the time when execute the python code

   b) Last updated time from HTML:

HTML structure:

```
  td x 1 including 
  two tables 
  each table have few "tr"
  and within "tr" have few "td" data inside
```

HTML:

```
  <td>

<table width="100%" border="4" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="white" align="center">
    <tbody> 
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="verd_black11">Last Updated: 18/08/2014 10:19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="verd_black11">All data delayed at least 15 minutes</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="4" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="white" align="center">
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr id="tr0" class="tableHdrB1" align="center">
      <td align="centre">C Aug-14 - 15000</td>
      <td align="right"> - </td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">9,904</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  </td>
```

Code:

```
import urllib2 
from bs4  import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "HTML:"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read())

table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id': 'tbody'})

rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        t = td.find(text=True)
        if t:
            text = t + ';'
        print text,
    print
```

Output from above code

```
C Aug-14 - 15000 ; - ; 5 ; 9,904
```

Expected output:

```
 C Aug-14 - 15000 ; - ; 5 ; 9,904  ; 18/08/2014 ; 13:48:00 ; 18/08/2014 ; 10:19
                                      (execute python code)    (last updated time)
```

Comment: This seems oddly familiar...

Answer (score 0):

To get the time that your code executes:

```
import datetime from datetime
code_executes = datetime.now()
```

Then pick the pieces you need from the code_executes tuple and format as a string for later insert to your print statement below

To get the Last Updated" bit you need to read the top table which you don't because it doesn't have the id attribute you specify.  If the html has only 2 tables,  you can probably drop the id specification for beautiful soup and you will get both tables.

To get the time from use str.startswith("Last Updated:") and just grab what comes after that (string slice will work)

In the end, tack on your two times to your line when you print it